# App Engine backup never finishes only clue is failure in map reduce worker_callback

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

Over the last few weeks we have repeatedly failed on doing a complete backup of the data store using the datastore admin tool.  We thought the issues had to do with quota errors we were running into so we switched our application from a free to a paid app and we still have problems.

Each time we are attempting to back up to the blobstore and what occurs is that the process never finishes.  We see the backup in our Pending Backups list but it never actually completes.  We only have a total of 43MB of data right now so we don't see it as a data transfer problem.  Looking at our default Task Queues it shows that we have two pending tasks one is a call to  /_ah/mapreduce/controller_callback and another is a call to  /_ah/mapreduce/worker_callback

The worker_callback racks up its retry count and the only error clue we have is on the Previous Run tab it shows the last http response code to be 500.  There is no error message, nothing shows up in our error logs, it just keeps trying over and over again.

We've been able to narrow the backup problems to a specific entity kind for a particular namespace but we can't figure out why that entity kind is failing whereas the others are not.  The major difference is the entity kind has a large number of embedded entities, but if the app engine is able to read / put those entities we can't understand why it seems to be having problems backing it up.  The particular namespace that the error occurs in has the largest data stored for that entity kind compared to the other namespaces we have setup.

We think if we can see what error is occurring in the worker_callback we may be able to figure out why the backup is failing, or what is wrong with our data that's preventing the backup. Is there something we need to setup / enable through settings / configuration files to give us more detailed information on the backup?  Or is there some other avenue we should explore to figure out how to investigate/fix this problem?

I should mention we are using the Java SDK as well as Objectify V3 to work with the data store.  We are also backing up data to the Blobstore.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well with the app engine team's help we figured what the problem was and we worked around the issue.  I want to give details in case anyone else runs into this problem.

From [issue 8363](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8363) the app engine team indicated that from their logs they could see that the map reduce failed because of the large number of properties that our entity kind had.  The specific entity kind that was causing the failure had a large number of variable properties that was generating errors when map reduce tried to write out a schema.  They indicated that the solution on their end was to ignore entities that were like this in the backup to make it so the backup worked successfully.

What we did to work around the issue and make the backup work was change how we told objectify to store out data.  The large number of properties were being created due to our use of the @embedded keyword on a HashMap() class member field.  Since the embedded keyword breaks down classes into individual components it was generating a large number of properties.  We switched the member field to be @serialized and then ran a conversion process to make it use the new serialized property.  This made the backup / restore work again.

You can read more about the differences between embedded and serialized on [objectify's website](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded)

Answer (score 0):

snielson, would you mind opening an issue on our Public issue tracker [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry). Remember to add your Application ID so we can further debug this specific scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: @I've opened ticket [8363](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8363&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).